# POSTGRES clients not shutting connections down

Tags: postgresql

The clients of a postgres server I am dealing with at the moment never explicitly close the connections and I am wondering what repercussions that might have.

However, if I run a lot of queries without closing the underlying connection the SQL:

```
SELECT pid, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, state FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Returns me:

```
cc=# SELECT pid, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, state FROM pg_stat_activity;

 pid | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port | state
-----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------
  69 |             |                 |             |
  71 |             |                 |             |
 297 | 172.17.0.1  |                 |       58434 | active
  67 |             |                 |             |
  66 |             |                 |             |
  68 |             |                 |             |
(6 rows)
```

That does not show a few rows, in fact it only shows the row describing the connection from which the query was issued.

To be fair I'd expect a lot more rows in there as I've run a plethora of requests, but I wonder if some permissions is needed or my query is correct at all.

The clients leave plenty of TCP sockets in TIME_WAIT - hence I'd expect the same in the server.

Comment: You need to run that query as a superuser (postgres) if you want to see all the connections

Comment: If your server is Linux, and you have root access, the connections will show up in the process list `ps ax|grep postgres` or `pgrep -a -u postgres`.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that if your clients do not close connections you should eventually run out of connections. `max_connections` in `postgresql.conf` sets the maximum connections before new connections will be denied access. As a last resort, you can mess with the tcp_keepalives... and tcp_user_timeout to automatically kick out users with too much idle time.

Comment: I am a superuser - usesuper is set to 't' in pg_user;

Comment: If they aren't explicitly closing the connection, then I guess they are doing it implicitly.  You can turn on log_disconnections to get at least some additional details.

Comment: @RichardHuxton he would still see a line per connection, it just that most of the fields would be NULL.

Comment: @jjanes - yeah - I was assuming that was why we had all the gaps in the screenshot. If that is from a superuser account then I'm puzzled why at least "state" isn't showing something.